# Trouble creating basic table

Tags: tables

I would like to create a table, which look like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning,calc,threeparttable} 
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow,tabularx,booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
\bf{Text A:} & \bf{Text B:} \\ 
\hline 
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat." & "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat." \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular} 
\end{document}
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: It is mandatory to use two tables? To set two texts parallel the package `\parallel` can be used

Comment: @A.F. That is basically how your example looks like ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on what you are really trying to achieve, here are several possibilities:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf}
%\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning,calc,threeparttable} 
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow,tabularx,booktabs}
\parskip 1em
\begin{document}
\noindent\hrulefill

Tiny to get specified text layout

{\centering\tiny\begin{tabular}{cc}
\textbf{Text A:} & \textbf{Text B:} \\ 
\parbox[t]{.45\textwidth}{\centering ``Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam 
nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat 
volutpat.''} & 
\parbox[t]{.45\textwidth}{\centering``Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam 
nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat 
volutpat.''}  \\ 
\end{tabular}\par}

Normalsize

{\centering\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
\textbf{Text A:} & \textbf{Text B:} \\ 
\hline 
\parbox[t]{.45\textwidth}{\centering ``Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam 
nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat 
volutpat.''} & 
\parbox[t]{.45\textwidth}{\centering``Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam 
nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat 
volutpat.''}  \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular}\par}

Without lines:

{\centering\begin{tabular}{cc}
\textbf{Text A:} & \textbf{Text B:} \\ 
\parbox[t]{.45\textwidth}{\centering ``Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam 
nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat 
volutpat.''} & 
\parbox[t]{.45\textwidth}{\centering``Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam 
nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat 
volutpat.''}  \\ 
\end{tabular}\par}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

EDIT to show how to make the top box locally exceed the margin, per OP's request.  I place it in a `\makebox[\textwidth]{...}` to achieve this, remembering to `\noindent` the `\makebox`.  The margin extent is shown with the `\hrulefill` at the top of the page.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf}
%\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning,calc,threeparttable} 
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow,tabularx,booktabs}
\parskip 1em
\begin{document}
\noindent\hrulefill

Footnotesize with margins exceeded to get specified text layout

\noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{\footnotesize\begin{tabular}{cc}
\textbf{Text A:} & \textbf{Text B:} \\ 
\parbox[t]{.6\textwidth}{\centering ``Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam 
nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat 
volutpat.''} & 
\parbox[t]{.6\textwidth}{\centering``Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam 
nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat 
volutpat.''}  \\ 
\end{tabular}}

Normalsize

{\centering\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
\textbf{Text A:} & \textbf{Text B:} \\ 
\hline 
\parbox[t]{.45\textwidth}{\centering ``Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam 
nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat 
volutpat.''} & 
\parbox[t]{.45\textwidth}{\centering``Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam 
nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat 
volutpat.''}  \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular}\par}

Without lines:

{\centering\begin{tabular}{cc}
\textbf{Text A:} & \textbf{Text B:} \\ 
\parbox[t]{.45\textwidth}{\centering ``Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam 
nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat 
volutpat.''} & 
\parbox[t]{.45\textwidth}{\centering``Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam 
nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat 
volutpat.''}  \\ 
\end{tabular}\par}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. If I would like to make the boxes wider, how do I do that?

Comment: @A.F.  Well for the basic `article` class, they are about as wide as they can go, without exceeding the margins (that line I drew at the top of the page is the margin extent).  If you are willing to change the document margins, I will post a revised answer.

Comment: It is not possible to overrule the margins, I mean, if I change "0.45\textwidth" my box's moved in wrong direction.

Comment: @A.F.  I have revised my answer to show how to use the `geometry` package to change the margins symmetrically.  Is that sufficient for your needs?  Or were you hoping to locally overrule the margins just for this table, but not the whole document.

Comment: I know how to change margins. I was hoping to overrule the margins, so it won't be depending whether the margins are 2, 3 og 4.

Comment: @A.F. Please see revision.

Comment: Perfect, you are my man.